# URL Rewrite not working for *.mp4 file extension

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke, mp4

I'm working on a DNN site, and I have a requirement to set up a URL rewrite to redirect incoming requests for a particular URL for an MP4 video to a different location. I can get it working if the incoming URL does not have the `*.mp4` file extension, but if the extension is there, the redirect fails and I get a 404.

I set up the rewrite by modifying the `SiteUrls.config` file to add the following entry:

```
<RewriterRule>
    <LookFor>.*VIDEOFILENAME.mp4(.*)</LookFor>
    <SendTo>http://externalsite/video/VIDEOFILENAME.mp4$1</SendTo>
</RewriterRule>
```

The above configuration results in a 404 if you try to browse to `mydnnsite/VIDEOFILENAME.mp4`.

However, the following configuration works just fine if you try to browse to `mydnnsite/VIDEOFILENAME` (without the `*.mp4` extension.)

```
<RewriterRule>
    <LookFor>.*VIDEOFILENAME(.*)</LookFor>
    <SendTo>http://externalsite/video/VIDEOFILENAME.mp4$1</SendTo>
</RewriterRule>
```

For whatever reason, the presence of the file extension is preventing the redirect from happening.

Comment: <RewriterRule>
    <LookFor>.*VIDEOFILENAME\.mp4(.*)</LookFor>
    <SendTo>http://externalsite/video/VIDEOFILENAME.mp4$1</SendTo>
</RewriterRule>

Comment: Thank you for the comment, however I just tried this out and it didn't work for me. It still results in a 404.

Answer (score 1):

IIS is probably setup to route requests with an `.mp4` extension to the static file handler, and it isn't getting to DNN to rewrite the request at all.  You can look at the Handler Mappings configuration in IIS to see if there's a mapping for `*.mp4`.

Ideally you'd be doing that redirect in IIS, anyway, rather than sending it to DNN, just to redirect back out.